# Nodemon not killing Node before trying to restart EEADINUSE error

Tags: node.js, api, nodemon, forever

this is my first node.js server.
I have created the server.js and it is running.
I installed nodemon and have it running and I also installed forever and got them running together.

Every time I make a change in my code and nodemon runs, it gets teh EADDRINUSE: error.

I have done

> lsof -i tcp:3000

and I get

> node    13837 p*********m   19u  IPv6 161703311      0t0  TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)

So i kill this PID using -kill - 9 PID

however it just starts up again and I get the error over and over.

What am i doing wrong :(

I just want:

- nodemon to restart when I change code
- watch terminal for api responses
- forever to keep running.

EDIT:

- I have since uninstalled FOREVER and just running nodemon.
- If I kill the port, it stays closed, HOWEVER if i make a change to code, I get the EEADINUSE error again.

What I think I have discovered is that nodemon is not killing the service before restarting it.

I found a forum post which suggested this:

> nodemon qudaserver.js --signal SIGTERM

However this also does not work

[image: Error when changing code]

Any other suggestions would be really appreciated.

My package.json code:

```
{
  "name": "qudaapi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "NodeJSAPI",
  "main": "qudaserver.js",
  "scripts": {},
  "author": "GAngel",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  }
}
```

My qudaserver.js code:

```
    const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app');


const port = process.env.port || 3000;
const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
```

Comment: Code snippets and config files would be helpful.

Comment: @c1moore thanks mate, maybe my serve file?  which config files, im new to node sorry

Comment: @c1moore added what I think people might need

Comment: Maybe try and run your server on a port other than 3000? Just to check if that's the only issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in you scripts section in package.json file `dev : "kill -9 $(lsof -i :3000) &>/dev/null | exit 0 nodemon server.js"`
so when ever you do a save, it explicitly kills the process on the port 3000 and starts again.

I Hope this is helpful.